# Erro sempre que utilizo Omit

Tags: node.js, typescript, express.js

Sempre tenho um erro que cobre o `Omit`. Não deixa de rodar o código, mas fica marcando o vscode e isso me incomoda.

```
constructor( {
        buyPrice,
        code,
        description,
        lovers,
        sellPrice,
        tags
      }: Omit<Product, 'id'> ){//digo os campos obrigatorios;
          this.buyPrice = buyPrice,
          this.code = code;
          this.sellPrice = sellPrice;
          this.tags = tags;
          this.lovers = lovers;
          this.description = description;
          this.id = uuid();
      }
```

Erro que o vscode aponta ao passar o mouse:

> Cannot find name 'Omit'.ts(2304)

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que esteja rodando o servidor com `ts-node-dev` ou o `nodemon` junto ao `ts-node` ou talvez `sucrase`, enfim existem várias opções. Mas imagino que esteja utilizando o `ts-node-dev` e passando o argumento `--transpile-only` isto faz com o ts-node apenas transpile o código para o javascript, ou seja, ele não checará o seu código typescript, por isso o seu código continua executando mesmo havendo esse erro.

Eu acho que existem duas possibilidades para esse problema estar ocorrendo:

- A sua versão do vscode está desatualizada
- Ou a versão do `typescript` que você instalou é antiga e ainda não contém esse type.

Espero ter ajudado!